# Android FusedLocationProviderClient use across Activities

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am starting location updates in one activity and stopping them in a subsequent activity in the flow of my app.

I create a final LocationUtilities class [code shown below with relevant parts] with static methods for requesting location updates. I got this pattern from somewhere on the internet and now wonder if I don't have a problem. This way the LocationCallback can be referenced across different activities.

My confusion comes from calling startLocationUpdates() with the Context of the start activity, and calling stopLocationUpdates() with the Context of the end activity. Does this work correctly?

Additionally, calling getFusedLocationProviderClient with different Activity Contexts.

Is there a problem here?

If there is a problem, could I save the starting Activity Context in a static field and use it in stopLocationUpdates() instead of the calling Activity Context?

What happens with location updates when my starting Activity is Destroyed as I move on to other Activities in my UI flow?

Please note: I have left out parts where I check for permissions and so on for brevity. I have started to notice strange actions in my app centered around location updates and wonder if this is the problem. It is not reproducible all the time. If I declare fusedLocationProviderClient as a static field, Studio complains about a memory leak.

```
private static LocationCallback locationCallback;

public static void startLocationUpdates(Context appContext) {
    locationCallback = new myLocationCallback();
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(appContext);
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
}

public static stopLocationUpdates(Context appContext) {
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(appContext);
    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
}

private static class myLocationCallback extends LocationCallback {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        :    :
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider running a service and listen to location changes there? In this case, you can run the service in one activity and then kill it in another one.

Comment: Thx sdex. I am considering doing this from a ForegroundService. However, this doesn't answer my questions above. And there seem to be complexities with stopping/unbinding from a foreground service that I am struggling with currently, from different activities. That's another post. From further testing, there appear to be NO ISSUES with using different instances of a fusedLocationProviderClient to start/stop updates; and there appear to be no issues with using a different Context in both cases.

Comment: In further testing, it may be that I used to hold my fusedLocationProvderClient instance in a static field in my class. However, I am very open to further comments about the validity of my code above and possible alternative design patterns.